# HP Proliant DL 380 G7: Which storage driver to use for Suse Linux 11

Tags: linux, hp, hp-proliant, sles, hp-smart-array

I was installing the Suse Linux 11 on HP Proliant DL 380 G7. during installation i got the error " NO usable hard disk found " i got stuck  for last 4 days ..need help on prioroty,

Comment: Did you contact HP Support?

Answer (score 5):

The HP ProLiant DL380 G7 uses a Smart Array P410 RAID controller. That version of SuSE may load either the [cciss driver or the newer hpsa driver](http://cciss.sourceforge.net/). Either way, both drivers are well-established and available to the system.

Did you create a RAID array/logical drive in the BIOS before booting the system?

As the system goes through its initialization sequence, you'll be presented with an option to hit `F8` to configure the Smart Array P410 controller in the system. This enters the Option ROM Configuration for Arrays (ORCA) utility. Create an array of an appropriate RAID level. The instructions for using this interface are on page 10 of the [Smart Array support manual](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00729544/c00729544.pdf). Save the changes and start your SuSE installer.

Answer (score 4):

An HP Proliant DL 380 has an on-board RAID controller that requires a specific driver module to use it, namely the HP/Compaq SmartArray `cciss` driver.

You need to load that before the OS can see the drives; if you have access to an emergency console during installation, run the following:

```
modprobe cciss
dmesg | tail
```

Comment: Include, load, whatever... +1 for conveying what I was aiming for.